# Get data from GCM into android device

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

is there a way to get data from "gcm notification". Here is a part of my json string which I send with gcm: "data":{"state":"deliver"}}. Here i am sending data using php curl request. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

GCM Send the data in JSON format.  You need to parse the JSON object to get the data which you are sending. The following code works for me :

```
 public void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent)
  {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if ("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE".equals(action)) {          
        message = intent.getStringExtra("data"); 
        String s=message.toString();
        parse_json_add(s);
    }
  }
```

Then to parse the JSON :

```
private void parse_json_add(String text) {
    if (text!= null) 
    { 
         JSONObject temp=new JSONObject(text);
         value=temp.get("state").toString();    
    }
}
```

Comment: I also thought the extra I had to get was "data", but I was getting a null String. It seems that the GCM library already parses the JSON. It only worked when I did `intent.getStringExtra("data");` ,i.e, the fields of data became extras.

Answer (score 4):

Whenever message arrives it will call OnMessage() method

you have to override this method

```
@Override
    protected void onMessage(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("onMessage",arg1.getExtras().getString("state"));
          }
```

Comment: You can improve you answer by saying that the fields of data become extras of the intent

Answer (score 1):

You can get data using the following code. For more information check the [Handling Received Data](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html#received_data).

```
String state = intent.getStringExtra("state");
```